# I have been given a cust_key I can use to import and display data from an API and need specific examples

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am barely getting around in HTML5, and trying to do PHP and AJAX and js all at the same time.   LOL.  I have been given a cust_key and an API that produces an XML output based off the criteria you send in via a url.  To integrate this feature to your site you will need to be able to pull information from an XML file.  I have an html table built, and the radio buttons, ... now I'd like to GET the info from the remote site (how do I attach my cust_key to results from all the radio buttons?) and display the results on my own site?

Comment: Please provide some specific examples of the API you're trying to use and the current HTML you have to receive your response.

Comment: If you go to http://www.rvcomfort.com/rvp/products/search.php and check the source you'll get on page pretty quickly.   I'd like to either use the table they've got, or build my own very like it on my page to act the same way.  I'd like the results to display below, like they've done, but images should have a link on them you can clik to go to another spot on the www.

Comment: From what I've figured out... I have to pass a request to that site, and include my key... and I will get something back in XML format that I have to display on my site.   Here is an example output from the API using your cust_key:
http://rvcomfort.com/rvp/dealers/roof_api.php?height=std&color=white&volt=120&ac_heat=ac&con_pump=n&power=std&btu=13,500&application=standard&cust_key=e14c522234aef9c7c848e3752518d0b1

Comment: I can build the basic page (header, one big column, footer) and get my table to display correctly, but now I get stuck trying to figure out how to have the return results display.  Do I use a submit button, and a clear button to avoid trying to do it real time?  How do I concantenate my key on the end of the results every time, whether any buttons are filled or not?